# Unknown property 'Integer.count_u18' visual force

Tags: class, controller, salesforce, visualforce

I searched a lot with google, but I didn't found a solution for my error.

I get the error Unknown property 'Integer.count_u18'.

I hope you can help me.

Thanks,
peX

**Visual Force Page**

```
<apex:page standardController="Account" extensions="Gruppenvertrag_c9">

<apex:form >

<apex:pageBlock Title="Long ID lautet">
    <apex:outputText value="{!Account.ID}"/>
</apex:pageBlock>

   <apex:pageBlock title="Count of Ages">
      <apex:pageBlockTable value="{!Einzelrisiko}" var="EZR">
         <apex:column value="{!EZR.Count_u18}"/>
         <apex:column value="{!EZR.Count_1822}"/>
         <apex:column value="{!EZR.Count_2227}"/>
         <apex:column value="{!EZR.Count_2732}"/>
         <apex:column value="{!EZR.Count_3237}"/>
         <apex:column value="{!EZR.Count_3742}"/>
         <apex:column value="{!EZR.Count_4247}"/>
         <apex:column value="{!EZR.Count_4752}"/>
         <apex:column value="{!EZR.Count_5257}"/>
         <apex:column value="{!EZR.Count_g57}"/>
      </apex:pageBlockTable>
   </apex:pageBlock>

</apex:form>

</apex:page>
```

**CLASS**

public class Gruppenvertrag_c9 {

```
  private Id accId {get; set;}
  public Gruppenvertrag_c9(ApexPages.StandardController stdcontroller) {
      accId = stdcontroller.getRecord().Id;
      }

  public Integer getEinzelrisiko() {

      //List<Einzelrisiko__c> listEZR = [SELECT COUNT() FROM Einzelrisiko__c WHERE Abgangsdatum__c = Null AND Unternehmens_Id_Long__c = :accId];
      List<Einzelrisiko__c> listEZR = [SELECT Alter__c FROM Einzelrisiko__c WHERE Abgangsdatum__c = Null AND Unternehmens_Id_Long__c = :accId];

      Integer Count_u18 = 0;
      Integer Count_1822 = 0;
      Integer Count_2227 = 0;
      Integer Count_2732 = 0;
      Integer Count_3237 = 0;
      Integer Count_3742 = 0;
      Integer Count_4247 = 0;
      Integer Count_4752 = 0;
      Integer Count_5257 = 0;
      Integer Count_g57 = 0;

      FOR(Einzelrisiko__c ein : listEZR) {
          IF(ein.Alter__c < 18) { Count_u18++; }
          IF(ein.Alter__c >18 && ein.Alter__c <=22) { Count_1822++; }
          IF(ein.Alter__c >22 && ein.Alter__c <=27) { Count_2227++; }
          IF(ein.Alter__c >27 && ein.Alter__c <=32) { Count_2732++; }
          IF(ein.Alter__c >32 && ein.Alter__c <=37) { Count_3237++; }
          IF(ein.Alter__c >37 && ein.Alter__c <=42) { Count_3742++; }
          IF(ein.Alter__c >42 && ein.Alter__c <=47) { Count_4247++; }
          IF(ein.Alter__c >47 && ein.Alter__c <=52) { Count_4752++; }
          IF(ein.Alter__c >52 && ein.Alter__c <=57) { Count_5257++; }
          IF(ein.Alter__c >57) { Count_g57++; }
      }

      return Count_u18;
      return Count_1822;
      return Count_2227;
      return Count_2732;
      return Count_3237;
      return Count_3742;
      return Count_4247;
      return Count_4752;
      return Count_5257;
      return Count_g57;

  }
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Problem with your `getEinzelrisiko()` method.This method is returning `Integer` and the `PageblockTable` value attribute should be of type `List`.

I have changed the `Visualforce Page` and `Apex Class` please check this.

`Visualforce :`

```
<apex:page standardController="Account" extensions="Gruppenvertrag_c9">
 <apex:form >
   <apex:pageBlock Title="Long ID lautet">
      <apex:outputText value="{!Account.ID}"/>
   </apex:pageBlock>
   <apex:pageBlock title="Count of Ages">
     <apex:pageBlockTable value="{!CountList}" var="EZR">`//Changed Value Attribute.`
       <apex:column value="{!EZR.Count_u18}"/>
       <apex:column value="{!EZR.Count_1822}"/>
       <apex:column value="{!EZR.Count_2227}"/>
       <apex:column value="{!EZR.Count_2732}"/>
       <apex:column value="{!EZR.Count_3237}"/>
       <apex:column value="{!EZR.Count_3742}"/>
       <apex:column value="{!EZR.Count_4247}"/>
       <apex:column value="{!EZR.Count_4752}"/>
       <apex:column value="{!EZR.Count_5257}"/>
       <apex:column value="{!EZR.Count_g57}"/>
    </apex:pageBlockTable>
  </apex:pageBlock>
 </apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

`Apex :`

```
public class Gruppenvertrag_c9 {
 private Id accId {get; set;}
 public List<CountClass> CountList {get;set;} //this list contains all the values and binded to Pageblocktable

 public Gruppenvertrag_c9(ApexPages.StandardController stdcontroller) {
   accId = stdcontroller.getRecord().Id;
   getEinzelrisiko();//called in the constructor.
 }

 public void getEinzelrisiko() {
 //List<Einzelrisiko__c> listEZR = [SELECT COUNT() FROM Einzelrisiko__c WHERE Abgangsdatum__c = Null AND Unternehmens_Id_Long__c = :accId];
 List<Einzelrisiko__c> listEZR = [SELECT Alter__c FROM Einzelrisiko__c WHERE Abgangsdatum__c = Null AND Unternehmens_Id_Long__c = :accId];

 CountList = new List<CountClass>();

 FOR(Einzelrisiko__c ein : listEZR) {

      CountClass cc = new CountClass();

      IF(ein.Alter__c < 18) { cc.Count_u18++; }
      IF(ein.Alter__c >18 && ein.Alter__c <=22) { cc.Count_1822++; }
      IF(ein.Alter__c >22 && ein.Alter__c <=27) { cc.Count_2227++; }
      IF(ein.Alter__c >27 && ein.Alter__c <=32) { cc.Count_2732++; }
      IF(ein.Alter__c >32 && ein.Alter__c <=37) { cc.Count_3237++; }
      IF(ein.Alter__c >37 && ein.Alter__c <=42) { cc.Count_3742++; }
      IF(ein.Alter__c >42 && ein.Alter__c <=47) { cc.Count_4247++; }
      IF(ein.Alter__c >47 && ein.Alter__c <=52) { cc.Count_4752++; }
      IF(ein.Alter__c >52 && ein.Alter__c <=57) { cc.Count_5257++; }
      IF(ein.Alter__c >57) { cc.Count_g57++; }

      CountList.add(cc);//adding each record to the list
   }
  }      
  public class CountClass
  {
    public  Integer Count_u18 {get;set;}
    public  Integer Count_1822 {get;set;}
    public  Integer Count_2227 {get;set;}
    public  Integer Count_2732 {get;set;}
    public  Integer Count_3237 {get;set;}
    public  Integer Count_3742 {get;set;}
    public  Integer Count_4247 {get;set;}
    public  Integer Count_4752 {get;set;}
    public  Integer Count_5257 {get;set;}
    public  Integer Count_g57 {get;set;}

     public CountClass()
     {
       Count_u18 = 0;
       Count_1822 = 0;
       Count_2227 = 0;
       Count_2732 = 0;
       Count_3237 = 0;
       Count_3742 = 0;
       Count_4247 = 0;
       Count_4752 = 0;
       Count_5257 = 0;
       Count_g57 = 0;
     }
  }     
}
```

Hope it helps you

Comment: Thanks for your support. But I get still an error Unknown property 'Gruppenvertrag_c9.CountClass.Count_u18'. Thanks, peX

Comment: Try setting the CountClass properties to public and check..i have edited the answer.

Comment: hey great thanks, but now I get the visualforce error "Collection size 1.172 exceeds maximum size of 1.000."

Comment: Limit the SOQL query size by filtering condition..Mark as this answer if it works for you

Comment: Ok. Do you have another idea to handle this query. First - I made for all age one query and I though this can be slower if I make it as above. Can I make this query maybe with an array?

Comment: its different but can be upto 200.000 records. Can I make the soql query with an array? if yes, the problem is solved.

Comment: Here are some workarounds http://kuldeeptyagi.blogspot.com/2011/05/salesforce-work-around-to-overcome-1000.html and http://www.infallibletechie.com/2012/10/collection-size-maximum-size-of-1000.html

Answer (score 0):

I've splitted the query into two queries and for the testing it works.
But, now I get a list of the query but I just want a count of the query. Could take a look into the code again.

Thanks,
Sascha

```
<apex:page standardController="Account" extensions="Gruppenvertrag_c55,Gruppenvertrag_c56">
 <apex:form >
   <apex:pageBlock Title="Long ID lautet">
      <apex:outputText value="{!Account.ID}"/>
   </apex:pageBlock>
   <apex:pageBlock title="Count of Ages">
     <apex:pageBlockTable value="{!CountList2}" var="EZR2">
       <apex:column value="{!EZR2.Count_u18}"/>
       <apex:column value="{!EZR2.Count_1822}"/>
       <apex:column value="{!EZR2.Count_2227}"/>
       <apex:column value="{!EZR2.Count_2732}"/>
       <apex:column value="{!EZR2.Count_3237}"/>
    </apex:pageBlockTable>
      </apex:pageBlock>
   <apex:pageBlock title="Count of Ages">
     <apex:pageBlockTable value="{!CountList}" var="EZR">
       <apex:column value="{!EZR.Count_3742}"/>
       <apex:column value="{!EZR.Count_4247}"/>
       <apex:column value="{!EZR.Count_4752}"/>
       <apex:column value="{!EZR.Count_5257}"/>
       <apex:column value="{!EZR.Count_g57}"/>
    </apex:pageBlockTable>
  </apex:pageBlock>
 </apex:form>
</apex:page>



public class Gruppenvertrag_c55 {
 private Id accId {get; set;}
 public List<CountClass> CountList {get;set;} //this list contains all the values and binded to Pageblocktable

 public Gruppenvertrag_c55(ApexPages.StandardController stdcontroller) {
   accId = stdcontroller.getRecord().Id;
   getEinzelrisiko();//called in the constructor.
 }

 public void getEinzelrisiko() {

 List<Einzelrisiko__c> listEZR = [SELECT Alter__c FROM Einzelrisiko__c WHERE Abgangsdatum__c = Null AND Unternehmens_Id_Long__c = :accId AND Alter__c >=42];

 CountList = new List<CountClass>();

 FOR(Einzelrisiko__c ein : listEZR) {

      CountClass cc = new CountClass();

      IF(ein.Alter__c >37 && ein.Alter__c <=42) { cc.Count_3742++; }
      IF(ein.Alter__c >42 && ein.Alter__c <=47) { cc.Count_4247++; }
      IF(ein.Alter__c >47 && ein.Alter__c <=52) { cc.Count_4752++; }
      IF(ein.Alter__c >52 && ein.Alter__c <=57) { cc.Count_5257++; }
      IF(ein.Alter__c >57) { cc.Count_g57++; }

      CountList.add(cc);//adding each record to the list
   }
  }      
  public class CountClass
  {

    public  Integer Count_3742 {get;set;}
    public  Integer Count_4247 {get;set;}
    public  Integer Count_4752 {get;set;}
    public  Integer Count_5257 {get;set;}
    public  Integer Count_g57 {get;set;}

     public CountClass()
     {

       Count_3742 = 0;
       Count_4247 = 0;
       Count_4752 = 0;
       Count_5257 = 0;
       Count_g57 = 0;
     }
  }     
}
```